# Assigning properties value to an array in powershell

Tags: powershell

I can use powershell to get the size of a queue using `Get-MsmqQueue -QueueType Private | Format-Table -Property BytesInQueue`.  And obviously I can assign the result of that to a variable i.e. $a = blah, but how do I assign the value of each queues BytesInQueue property to an array so that I can do math against the values?  For example say I want to know the total of all BytesInQueue, and/or the min/max values.  I vaguely understand arrays, but I haven't quite figured out how to extract the value from a property and assign it to an array.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You just want to sum up all the values?(:

Comment: Well short answer is yes, but I really want to understand how to create the array so that I can do whatever I want with the values as I run into this kind of thing often and want to understand how to get pieces of information into an array.  But yes, for the moment I want to know how to get all of the values and sum them into a single answer (Total BytesInQueue = X).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is a little broad; PowerShell has many ways to deal with collections.  Doing math , like Sum, Min, Max is conveniently accomplished with the `Measure-Object` cmdlet.

```
$Queues = Get-MsmqQueue -QueueType Private
$TotalQueuedBytes = ($Queues | Measure-Object -Property BytesInQueue -Sum).Sum
```

`$TotalQueuedBytes` will be the sum of bytes in all queues. Note that you can send the Output of `Get-MsmqQueue` directly to `Measure-Object` without the intermediate variable.  However, it's likely you'll want to slice & dice the information etc...

Importantly `$Queues` is an array. PowerShell automatically types an assignment as an object array `[Object[]]` when the right hand side of the assignment statement generates more than 1 Item.

You can wrap the right hand side in an array subexpression `@(...)` to guarantee an array is returned.

```
$Queues = @(Get-MsmqQueue -QueueType Private)
```

This will guarantee `$Queues` is an array even if the `Get-MsmqQueue` command returns a scalar.

If you just want a list of bytes you can unroll the property into an array like:

```
$QueuedBytes = @((Get-MsmqQueue -QueueType Private).BytesInQueue)
```

This will give you a flat array of the BytesInQueue property.

So the best way to create an array is to let PowerShell do it for you, however you can manually create one like:

```
$Array = @()
```

Check out [about_Arrays](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_arrays?view=powershell-7.1) for a more robust explanation.

Comment: Thank you Steven.  I will need to play with each of these before I fully understand it all.  I was already creating an array (of sorts) but I was getting "extra" data inside it.  I get your direct answer but I want to better understand the process of "unrolling the property".  Just for clarification, I know in a SQL query I would need to insure my data was captured as integers, is that applicable in PS too?  As in, when you declare the variable or when you "unroll" the property, is it advisable to declare it as an integer?

Comment: PowerShell is type dynamic, and has a rich dynamic conversion capability. While you can type constrain a variable it is rare to need to. If you unroll a property PowerShell will maintain the type of the property.  This is too big a topic for a comment. If you are down for some reading PowerShell In Action by Bruce Payatte covers typing well.

Comment: Nice, but note that in `@(Get-MsmqQueue -QueueType Private).BytesInQueue` the `@(...)` is unnecessary and that [member enumeration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44620191/45375) does _not_ guarantee that the result is an array (it applies pipeline logic); for that you'd have to use `$QueuedBytes = @((Get-MsmqQueue -QueueType Private).BytesInQueue)` or `[array] $QueuedBytes = (Get-MsmqQueue -QueueType Private).BytesInQueue`.

Comment: Agreed. I think I inadvertently carried it over from the preceding example. I’ll update that.

Answer (score 1):

Abe here! Winner of 2013, and 2015 Bingo games(; (*thought it was gonna be something fancy huh*).

Anyways, to put it simply, arrays are just a collection of *things*. Creating an array is as easy as assigning comma separated values to a variable.

```
$Array = "im","in","an","array"

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $Array
im
in
an
array

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $Array.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                                      
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                                      
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array
```

Cool, now how would can I create a blank array and add *stuff* to it?

We can use the **[Array subexpression operator `@( )`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.1#array-subexpression-operator--)**.

- `$Array = @()`

We can take values, and append those values to the array using the [plus-equals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-arrays?view=powershell-7.1#plus-equals-) symbol(s): `+=`:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $Array = @()
$Array += "One"

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $Array
One

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $Array.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                                      
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                                      
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array
```

Notice how the variable (`$Array`) is still considered an array with only one value inside it? It's due to explicitly assigning it as an array using `@()`.

Well, although they are getting added to it, this is whats considers as a *Fixed Array*. In other words, each time it *appends* an item (object) to the array, it tears it down completely, and reccreates it with the newly added item. So a lot of Posh admins frown down on using it, but it's really not bad. It's just *Computationaly Expensive* which will slow down your scripts performance.

So, what's a *faster* alternative Mr. 2013, 2015 Bingo winner? Well, im glad you asked! We do have an alternative which is my go-to when appending to an array, and that's an **ArrayList**. Part of `Systems.Collections` Namespace in dotNet, there's a couple of ways to *instatiate* an ArrayList, which we'll skip some, and stick to one for now.

```
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$ArrayList = @()

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> [System.Collections.ArrayList]$ArrayList = @()
$null = $ArrayList.Add('One') #by default, the index number added to the array is displayed to the host, so we can null it.
$ArrayList
One

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $ArrayList.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                                      
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                                      
True     True     ArrayList                                System.Object
```

So, what's the big idea? Looks the same....well, true. The end. Jk! Put simply, the ArrayList is no longer a *Fixed Array* and doesn't need to be torn down each time something is added to it using the `.Add()` method due to it being assigned the type data of `ArrayList` keeping your script running at optimal speed.

To not take away from @Stevens answer, I won't be answering your question, and wanted to provide my 2 cents on how I understand array. Here are some useful links you can look at to get a better understanding of them so this doesnt become a post longer than it should be:

1. [Everything you wanted to know about arrays](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-arrays?view=powershell-7.1#plus-equals-)
2. [How to create and use PowerShell ArrayList](https://www.spguides.com/powershell-arraylist/)

**MSFT quote on Array Types**

> By default, an array in PowerShell is created as a [PSObject[]] type. This allows it to contain any type of object or value. This works because everything is inherited from the PSObject type.

Hopefully, this helps steer you in the right direction as im no expert ( *except at bingo - even tho its a game of luck* ). Just your average powereshell user here.

Comment: Thank you Abraham, while I very much appreciate the meal, I always like to learn how to fish.  I've been reading up on arrays and your answer helps make a lot of sense out of what I've been reading.

Comment: Nice, but note that regular PowerShell arrays are of type `[object[]]` (the true root of the .NET type hierarchy), not `[psobject[]]`. In fact, `[psobject]` wrappers can cause subtle bugs - see [GitHub issue #5579](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5579).